# Can i put hidden token inside email while sending email through laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, email, laravel-mail

I want to send a email to the user from my laravel application. But i want to add a hidden token in that email so that user cannot see it and when user reply to that mail i can read that token and further use it.
Is it even possible?
I am using laravel 5.6 and sending emails using SMTP

Comment: The user can see everything that's in the email if they're technically inclined enough to view the HTML source. Why does it matter if they can see it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it but none is ideal. Let's start with your idea:

- You can add a token within the message, but it can never be invisible, the contents of the message have to be fully visible. Even so, if the reply simply doesn't contain the original message, you will lose the reference

The standard way of tracking replies is based on [Message-ID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4), since every email has to have unique `Message-ID`. Since you mentioned that you are using SMTP, that allows you to setup `Message-ID` upfront, otherwise, you'd retrieve it after the message is sent. It helps in a way that you can store that value in the database and automatically link it to the recipient.

Then, you'd look for `In-Reply-To:` and/or `References:` headers which should mention the original `Message-ID` if the reply is properly formatted, which doesn't have to be the case.

Ultimately, depending on your use case, you might not need any of these and you could just keep the sent email based on the recipient email address and extra information that you wanted to pass in the email within your database. Assuming that you'd expect an email from the same recipient email address, you could just figure out the token locally.